# pandas : INDEXING a GroupBy object with a ARRAY OF COLUMN

Tags: pandas, indexing, pandas-groupby

In Python for Data Analysis Book by Wes McKinne, it is mentioned that

> df.groupby('key1')[['data2']]

is syntactically similar to

> df[['data2']].groupby(df['key1'])

but the result produced by both statement are **different**. Moreover result of ***df.groupby('key1')[['data2']]*** is similar as ***df.groupby('key1')***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key1' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a'],
               'key2' : ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one'],
               'data1' : np.random.randn(5),
               'data2' : np.random.randn(5)})
df

key1    key2    data1   data2
0   a   one 1.103015    1.142491
1   a   two 0.758543    -0.820083
2   b   one -1.749065   0.445968
3   b   two 0.337383    0.372625
4   a   one -0.065351   -0.207071
```

---

```
a = df.groupby('key1')[['data2']]

for key, data in a:
  print(key)
  print(data)

a
  key1 key2     data1     data2
0    a  one  1.103015  1.142491
1    a  two  0.758543 -0.820083
4    a  one -0.065351 -0.207071
b
  key1 key2     data1     data2
2    b  one -1.749065  0.445968
3    b  two  0.337383  0.372625
```

---

```
c = df.groupby('key1')
for key, data in c:
  print(key)
  print(data)

a
  key1 key2     data1     data2
0    a  one  1.103015  1.142491
1    a  two  0.758543 -0.820083
4    a  one -0.065351 -0.207071
b
  key1 key2     data1     data2
2    b  one -1.749065  0.445968
3    b  two  0.337383  0.372625
```

---

```
b = df[['data2']].groupby(df['key1'])
for key, data in b:
  print(key)
  print(data)

a
      data2
0  1.142491
1 -0.820083
4 -0.207071
b
      data2
2  0.445968

3  0.372625
```

---

Why the results stored in variable **a** and **b** are different when they should be similar as both are same but written differently mentioned by writer. Also why the results are similar for variable **a** and **c** as result of **a** should be different than **c** because of indexing . I don't understand the behaviour .

Comment: Sorry, what is the question?

Comment: @gcoronel99  updated thread . please check agin